# Boost::Property_Tree Settings

Tags: c++, boost, settings

I am trying to configurate my XML file, thanks to Boost::Property_Tree.
Chat I want is :

```
<configuration>
<message>
<first>10</first>
</message>
</configuration>
```

And what I have is :

```
<configuration><message>first>10</first></message></configuration>
```

I found that I had to use

```
boost::property_tree::xml_writer_settings<char> settings(' ', 1);
write_xml(file, XMLobjectL, std::locale(), settings);
```

But this doesn't compile.
Errors are :

> IntelliSense: no instance of "write_xml" matches the argument list
>   argument types are: (const std::string, boost::property_tree::ptree,
>   std::locale,
>   boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_writer_settings)
>
> error C2664: 'void
>   boost::property_tree::xml_parser::write_xml(const
>   std::string &,const Ptree &,const std::locale &,const
>   boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_writer_settings &)' :
>   cannot convert argument 4 from
>   'boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_writer_settings' to
>   'const boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_writer_settings &'

Do you have any idea ?
I am using Boost 1.57.0 and MVSC++
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to help overload resolution.

That said, consider using `xml_writer_make_settings`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f122cc9fe9e9168)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

using namespace boost::property_tree;

int main() {
    ptree XMLobjectL;
    XMLobjectL.put("configuration.message.first", 10);

    write_xml("test.xml", XMLobjectL, std::locale(), xml_writer_make_settings<ptree::key_type>(' ', 1u));
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Why did you put 1u instead of 1 ? Thank you for your help anyway !

Comment: @NorthernLight it's a good habit. If you can make arguments match exactly, you'll reduce the risk of getting "no best conversion" in overload resolution